Can I modify my zip so iOS won't auto unpack it on download?
I maintain a free tool to produce books in DAISY format for the blind.  One of the more widely-used DAISY reader programs is Dolphin EasyReader which has an iOS version.  When "side-loading" a book into EasyReader (rather than obtaining it from a library listing), the user needs to point EasyReader at a ZIP file (with .zip extension) containing the DAISY book.  Pointing EasyReader at an unpacked folder does not work.
When blind users download a DAISY book produced by my tool, if they're on iOS, their device automatically unpacks the zip file into a folder.  That causes confusion, because EasyReader needs to be given the non-unpacked .zip file.
Currently, I add a file called 0000.txt containing my message about how if they're having trouble launching it in EasyReader then they should go up one level and find the original .zip file rather than the unpacked folder.  But this was (a) hard to write without it looking like I'm disrespecting their operating system, (b) even harder to write in lots of different languages other than English and (c) still requires the user to take extra steps.
I know Apple devices can be configured on the user side not to auto unpack .zip files, but rather than tell my users to change their settings, I'd much rather set something on my side if possible.  Is there anything I can do to the zip file that says "hey iOS, if you're seeing this, please don't auto unpack this particular zip file" (but without actually corrupting the zip file because EasyReader still needs to unpack it)?
(I'm unsure from the user reports whether the auto extraction is being performed by Safari or by Files.  Either way, I'd like to stop it because in this particular case it's not helping.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be an option to change the extension as .zip is required by most DAISY readers.)

Does EasyReader need a .zip extension or does it also open ZIP files with a different suffix (e.g. book.leavemealone)?

Unfortunately it needs .zip (otherwise I'd have used .daisy)

I downloaded a zip file with Safari, it got stored into the Downloads folder as is (without unpacking) and stayed packed when I opened the folder in Files. Can you share a link from your website so we can test with a actual file your users download as well?

Even better to try one of the sample zip files from the DAISY Consortium https://daisy.org/info-help/document-archive/sample-files/ it's possible that your device has different settings than my user's, and unfortunately I wasn't standing over his shoulder so I don't 100% know what he did exactly, but he somehow ended up with the zip file being unpacked when it was supposed to be opened in EasyReader.

Doesn't automatically unpack for me, but apparently (according to documentation I found) it should?! How does your user proceed once they clicked on the link and confirmed the download? Do they open the Download popup in Safari and tap the ZIP there (option 1)? Do they switch to Files and browse to the Download folder (option 2)?

I don't know, but I guess we need to support people taking either option.  Mac Safari has a Setting under General called "open safe files after downloading" which is on by default, and if you turn it off it stops unpacking the zip.  I don't know if iOS has the same.  Perhaps you turned yours off at some point?  I'd rather avoid having to tell users to check a setting before downloading a zip though.

There is no such option on iOS. And even with that enabled, your users should still see the zip file directly in the Downloads folder. Which makes me wonder how exactly your users access the downloaded file to add it to EasyReader because there are steps to take between accepting the download and seeing the unpacked files. iOS doesn‘t automatically open the folder for you. But without further insights, it‘s hard to propose anything.
